# Multiple machines in the LAN are appending lines to a server file. How do I avoid possible clashes?

Tags: .net, file, io

(.NET environment)

There are several client machines B ... N which access a text file on server A in order to append a single line to it (these lines are instructions to A to do something, the file itself is a FIFO instruction queue). The file is small, and most of the time completely empty. There are apps on A itself appending lines to this file.

Machines B to N do write only to this file, but it is unforeseeable when, so access violations are likely to occur every so often.

Machine A checks this file every second, removes all currently existing lines line by line (FIFO), while executing said instructions. Of course, there is a high potential for access violations here (as clients happen to currently append to the file), but this is quite negligible, as the intended operation simply can be aborted (because a retry happens anyway each second and timing is not that crucial).

The main problem I have is with the client machines. How do I ensure, that I can still safely append to the file on A, when A (or another client) is actually manipulating it? Should I just follow A's strategy and try and try every second, until it succeeds, or is there a special I/O setting for exactly these purposes?

Comment: OK, I'll be blunt - this is a horrible design. It goes out of its way to actually create opportunities for corruption and race conditions. Why not something simple such as 1) Remote machines create file**s** each with a name guaranteed to be unique in a temp directory on the same file system as the watched directory 2) then they remote machine atomically **moves** each file into the watched directory 3) watching process sorts files by created timestamp and deletes files when done with each one.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, thanks for your input; I might actually be going the suggested way. (Only that I don't feel "something simple such as" to be applicable here, as it's clearly more elaborate ;) - If you bother to turn your suggestion into an answer, and no more suitable or feasible suggestions are provided, I'd happily accept it as the answer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, why a temp directory and not a dedicated directory common to all clients?

Comment: You need some sort of atomic signal to tell the scanning process "It's OK to read this file".  The easiest way to do that is with a file rename/move to another directory, as those actions are atomic if done within the same filesystem. You need the signal because there's no way for the scanning process to know that a file is complete without such a signal - there could have been an error that resulted in only a partial file being written.  It's a temp directory only in that it's not the same directory that's being scanned - the file will be in that directory only temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing a single file makes error detection impossible - if a remote client crashes while holding a lock on the file and has only partially completed its write, what happens?

You also have to worry about locking and corruption from simultaneous updates if you don't use locking.  And locking files across networks can be extremely problematic.

The easiest way to solve this is to eliminate the need for file locking and simultaneous updates to the same file altogether by relying on the fact that file renames or moves *within the same file system* are atomic.

One way to do this would be:

1. Change the scanning process to scan for all *files* in a directory, sorted by creation date.
2. The remote client(s) creates *new* file in a working/temporary directory in the same shared filesystem as the directory the scanner is scanning.  Each file should be named in a pattern that guarantees a unique name.
3. Once the remote client has successfully written the entire file, the remote client process renames/moves into the scanned directory using a call [such as `RenameFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.renamefile(v=vs.110).aspx) on Windows or `rename()` on POSIX systems.  Note that the call used must be an atomic operation - both `RenameFile()` and `rename()` are documented as being atomic. (If `RenameFile()` won't allow moving the file to another directory, have the remote client start off with a file name such as "ASDF.ignore" or "ASDF.inwork", then use `RenameFile()` to remove the extension, and have the scanning process ignore files with such an extension.)